# Pycharm does not install correctly on ubuntu 16.04, it disappears every time I close it

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, pycharm

Im a Linux newbie.
I have Ubuntu 16.04.

I had pycharm installed and path added to the Ubuntu, but suddenly it is disappeared and it looks like it never existed!!

Now I am trying to install it again, I look at `sudo dpkg --list` and I cannot see that.

So I assume it is not on my system. However, when I install it as it mentioned in on the pycharm website by `tar -xzf pycharm-2017.1.4.tar.gz` and then run the sh file in the bin folder, it still has some issues.
MEaning that when i run pycharm.sh it runs, but after closing pycharm it disappear again and if I wanna use it again I should go to pycharm/bin/ and run pycharm.sh.

I should mention that I have all the JDK and Java requirement installed correctly before.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here, or can you tell me how I can remove all the dependency and path and possible things related to pycharm and reinstall it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch PyCharm, go to Tools, then click "Create a Desktop Entry".  It will now be accessible from the dash.

What you are executing is *not* an installer, it's just the executable to start the program.  The core software makes its Desktop launcher if you tell it to but not otherwise.

Comment: It was tools> "create a desktop entry..."
Thanks